# Single event function for text, check box, select input using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to do same things when following event occur on a form

1) An input text box value is changed by keyboard or mouse(pasting) 
2) A checked box is checked/unchecked
3) A select option is changed

currently I am doing

```
$(':text').on('input', function()  {
  //Same code   
}

$(':checkbox').on('change', function()  {
  //Same code
}

$('select').on('change', function()  {
  //Same code
}
```

but i want to write single function for all there events like

```
  $(':text', ':checkbox', 'select' ).on('???', function()  {
      //Same code   
    }
```

Please help me on it

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like this. But this will trigger both change and input events for the :text.

```
$(':checkbox, :text, select').on('change input',function(e)  {
    //code
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLektdn/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS class to these input boxes and use that class as your jQuery selector for binding your event.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="changable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="changable" />
```

and jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("change",".changable",function(e){
      var _this=$(this);
     // do something now.
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. for input text box i want to do when the input value is changed by keyboard or mouse(pasting). not when i click. Same as select option

Comment: Then put your common stuff in a function and call than on various events.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using @Shyju's answer, as it is much more scalable and friendly, but based off of your question, here is an implementation.

Listen to the document for click events and delegate it to the selectors you pass in:

```
$(document).on('click', ':text, :checkbox, select', function()  {
  doFunction();
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/speak/mt8hqe29/)

Answer (score 0):

Bind your single/multiple event/s with multiple elements using [***class attribute***](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp). Assign same class to all elements and find the event type that has been fired. According to the fired event *code* your implementation.

Try this way :

***HTML :***

```
<input class="elements" type="text" />
<input class="elements" type="checkbox" />
<select class="elements">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>

<input class="elements" type="button" value="Click here" />
```

***jQuery :***

```
$(".elements").on("change click", function(e){
    var nodes = e.target;
    if(nodes.nodeName == "INPUT"){
        if(nodes.type == "text" && e.type == "change"){
            // code goes here
            alert("Input changed");
        }else if(nodes.type == "checkbox" && e.type == "change"){
           // code goes here
            alert("Checkbox state changed");
        }else if(nodes.type == "button" && e.type == "click"){
            alert("Button is clicked");
        }
    }
    else if(nodes.nodeName == "SELECT" && e.type == "change"){
        // code goes here
       alert("Select option changed");
    }
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/8ut6gsxr/)

**Resources :**

[***event.type***](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/)

[***event.target.nodeName***](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)